# Why don't I see an overscroll glow on a HTC Desire HD

Tags: android, htc-android, htcsense, android-overscoll

I have an app that uses several lists and scroll views. 
On a Nexus S I see an orange glow if I overscroll the lists.

On a HTC Desire HD the list simply stops at the top, there is no bounce or overscroll visible.

I tried to set the overscrollmode of my listviews to always but that changed nothing.

Is there somethign I need to enable inside my app to enable the overscroll behaviour or is the overscroll functionality simply missing on HTC Devices?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that this over-scroll effect is dependant to the Android version on the handset. I saw this on the emulator - with the latest SDK version (12) this was visible, with earlier - not.

Comment: It was introduced with Gingerbread. But The Desire HD has the Gingerbread running already.